# Why is C# IntelliSense delayed compared to VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, intellisense

In VB.NET projects, errors are highlighted immediately after cursor leaves the line. In C#, I have to wait several seconds for IntelliSense to highlight it. Also, the C# version doesn't show all project errors in "Errors List", unless you start to build it. Actually, it seems to work differently in every way. Is it possible to adjust that behavior?

I am using both Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because VB.NET does full background compilation whenever the IDE is idle, so it always has the latest information ready. C# doesn't do this and instead have a separate process that creates the IntelliSense information.

You can't really adjust it without a lot of work or buying some third party tool. It's one of the differences between the languages, the VB.NET team concentrates on certain aspects and the C# team on others.

Though I think some of the addins you can buy (possibly [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) and others) are advertising better IntelliSense if you really want it.

Comment: I would say this isn't *entirely* accurate, since ReSharper does background compilation on C#, inside VS.

Comment: Can ReSharper do the same job as VB.NET background compiler does?

Comment: @Nick Craver: Adjusted my answer slightly to try to cover that.

Comment: @Sphynx: I'm not sure it's 100% the same, since I don't do VB, haven't since 2003, but it does everything I'd want, including instant compilation warnings...I'm on a pretty beefy machine though, so not sure if it lags a little on other hardware or not.

Comment: I tried out a Resharper trial a year ago and thought it was too slow (not very slow, but just enough to be annoying), but that was on my previous machine which was a couple of years old by then and was just a mid range when I bought it.

Comment: @ho1: Also remember that VS 2010 is a lot more lightweight/snappier than VS 2008 to start with, with much better VM overhead, so all plugins got a nice performance boost there as well.

Answer (score 4):

When using Visual Basic, Visual Studio instantly compiles the new code, whereas with C#, only syntax errors are highlighted directly, and compile errors after you build the code.